# Unflatten nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

What would be the cleanest way to convert this

```
{"a.b.c[0].key1": 1, "a.b.c[1].key2": 2, "a.b.c[3].key3": 3}
```

Into this

```
{"a": {"b": {"c": [{"key1": 1}, {"key2": 2}, None, {"key3": 3}]}}}
```

- the dictionary keys may be anything.
- the length of the list may vary.
- the depth of the dictionary may vary.
- if there are missing values in the list the value must be None.
- if values are repeated the last one declared is the one that counts.

I came up with the following working example.

Was wondering if we could find a better solution for our community.

```
def unflatten(data):
    if type(data) != dict:
        return None
    regex = r'\.?([^.\[\]]+)|\[(\d+)\]'
    result_holder = {}
    for key,value in data.items():
        cur = result_holder
        prop = ""
        results = re.findall(regex, key)
        for result in results:
            prop = int(prop) if type(cur) == list else prop
            if (type(cur) == dict and cur.get(prop)) or (type(cur) == list and len(cur) > prop):
                cur = cur[prop]
            else:
                if type(cur) == list:
                    if type(prop) is int:
                        while len(cur) <= prop:
                            cur.append(None)
                cur[prop] = list() if result[1] else dict()
                cur = cur[prop]
            prop = result[1] or result[0]

        prop = int(prop) if type(cur) == list else prop

        if type(cur) == list:
            if type(prop) is int:
                while len(cur) <= prop:
                    cur.append(None)

        print(len(cur), prop)
        cur[prop] = data[key]

    return result_holder[""] or result_holder
```

Comment: Can you rely on the `.` as a reliable separator for the keys? Meaning that in your string, there will never be something that is intended to be a key name that contains a `.`?

Comment: If the depth of the dict is unknown, you're most likely going to need some recursive function

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks. Updated the question.

Comment: @benvc, yes you can.

Comment: In your example, `cur.get(prop)` will throw an error when `type(cur) == list`.

Comment: thanks @ benvc, fixed it. Now it works well... but the code is ugly as hell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
d = {"a.b.c[0].key1": 1, "a.b.c[1].key2": 2, "a.b.c[3].key3": 3}
from itertools import groupby
import re
def group_data(data):
  new_results = [[a, [i[1:] for i in b]] for a, b in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
  arrays = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in groupby(sorted(new_results, key=lambda x:x[0].endswith(']')), key=lambda x:x[0].endswith(']'))]
  final_result = {}
  for a, b in arrays:
     if a:
       _chars = [[c, list(d)] for c, d in groupby(sorted(b, key=lambda x:re.findall('^\w+', x[0])[0]), key=lambda x:re.findall('^\w+', x[0])[0])]
       _key = _chars[0][0]
       final_result[_key] = [[int(re.findall('\d+', c)[0]), d[0]] for c, d in _chars[0][-1]]
       _d = dict(final_result[_key])
       final_result[_key] = [group_data([_d[i]]) if i in _d else None for i in range(min(_d), max(_d)+1)]
     else:
        for c, d in b:
           final_result[c] = group_data(d) if all(len(i) >1 for i in d) else d[0][0]
  return final_result

print(group_data([[*a.split('.'), b] for a, b in d.items()]))
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': [{'key1': 1}, {'key2': 2}, None, {'key3': 3}]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function would probably be much easier to work with and more elegant.

This is partly pseudocode, but it may help you get thinking.

I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure it should work so long as you don't have any lists that are directly elements of other lists. So you can have dicts of dicts, dicts of lists, and lists of dicts, but not lists of lists.

```
def unflatten(data):
    resultDict = {}
    for e in data:
        insertElement(e.split("."), data[e], resultDict)

    return resultDict


def insertElement(path, value, subDict):
    if (path[0] is of the form "foo[n]"):
        key, index = parseListNotation(path[0])
        if (key not in subDict):
            subDict[key] = []

        if (index >= subDict[key].len()):
            subDict[key].expandUntilThisSize(index)

        if (subDict[key][index] == None):
            subDict[key][index] = {}

        subDict[key][index] = insertElement(path.pop(0), value, subDict[key][index])

    else:
        key = path[0]

        if (path.length == 1):
            subDict[key] = value
        else:
            if (key not in subDict):
                subDict[key] = {}

            subDict[key] = insertElement(path.pop(0), value, subDict[key])

    return subDict;
```

The idea is to build the dictionary from the inside, out. E.g.:

For the first element, first create the dictionary `

- `{key1: 1}`,

Then assign that to an element of a new dictionary

- `{c : [None]}, c[0] = {key1: 1}`

Then assign that dictionary to the next element `b` in a new dict, like 
 - `{b: {c : [{key1: 1}]}`

Assign that result to `a` in a new dict 
 - `{a: {b: {c : [{key1: 1}]}}`

And lastly return that full dictionary, to use to add the next value.

---

If you're not familiar with recursive functions, I'd recommend practicing with some simpler ones, and then writing one that does what you want but for input that's only dictionaries.

General path of a dictionary-only recursive function:

Given a path that's a list of attributes of nested dictionaries ( `[a, b, c, key1]` in your example, if c weren't a list):

```
Start (path, value):

If there's only item in your path, build a dictionary setting 
  that key to your value, and you're done.

If there's more than one, build a dictionary using the first 
  element as a key, and set the value as the output of Start(path.remove(0), value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation on how to achieve the desired results. Not as pretty as I would like though, so I expect there is a much more elegant way. Probably more regex than is really necessary if you spent a bit more time on this, and also seems like the `break` approach to handling the final key is probably just an indicator that the loop logic could be improved to eliminate that sort of manual intervention. That said, hopefully this is helpful in the process of refining your approach here.

```
import re

def unflatten(data):
    results = {}
    list_rgx = re.compile(r'[^\[\]]+\[\d+\]')
    idx_rgx = re.compile(r'\d+(?=\])')
    key_rgx = re.compile(r'[^\[]+')
    for text, value in data.items():
        cur = results
        keys = text.split('.')
        idx = None
        for i, key in enumerate(keys):
            stop = (i == len(keys) - 1)          
            if idx is not None:
                val = value if stop else {}  
                if len(cur) > idx:
                    cur[idx] = {key: val}
                else:
                    for x in range(len(cur), idx + 1):
                        cur.append({key: val}) if x == idx else cur.append(None)         
                if stop:
                    break
                else:
                    cur[idx].get(key)
                    idx = None
            if stop:
                cur[key] = value
                break
            elif re.match(list_rgx, key):
                idx = int(re.search(idx_rgx, key).group())
                key = re.search(key_rgx, key).group()
                cur.setdefault(key, [])
            else:
                cur.setdefault(key, {})
            cur = cur.get(key)
    print(results)
```

Output:

```
d = {"a.b.c[0].key1": 1, "a.b.c[1].key2": 2, "a.b.c[3].key3": 3}
unflatten(d)

# {'a': {'b': {'c': [{'key1': 1}, {'key2': 2}, None, {'key3': 3}]}}}
```